# Script to configure Synaptics touchpad

Tags: sh

I have a shell script to configure Synaptics touchpad settings at login.

### Background

You configure the touchpad with the `synclient` command. Its usage is

> synclient [-lV?] [var1=value1 [var2=value2] ...]

For example:

- `synclient PalmDetect=1` — to set a single setting
- `synclient PalmDetect=1 PalmMinZ=10` — to set multiple

I'm trying to use my script itself as a configuration file by playing around with heredocs and grep. The script greps out all comment lines (starting with `#`) and then passes everything in the heredoc as arguments to `synclient`. Is this code clean? How could I improve it?

### Script

```
#!/bin/sh
# script to configure Synaptic touchpad settings
# This script treats itself as a configuration file.

<< END_OF_SETTINGS grep -v '^#' | xargs synclient

# Try to disable touchpad while typing
PalmDetect=1
PalmMinZ=100

# Allow three-finger middle button tap, click
TapButton3=2
ClickFinger3=2

END_OF_SETTINGS
```